# aspectj for Android studio - where is AJDT plugin

Tags: aop, aspectj, ajdt

How do i install AJDT for android studio. I know there is one for eclipse but i cant find anything in android studio. What i would like to do is run security checks on every one of my method calls before they launch. I've tried from this site [AJDT](http://eclipse.org/ajdt/) but this is for eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Studio is an Android-aware version of IntelliJ. IntelliJ has no tooling support for AspectJ.  There are two solutions that I can think of:

1. Use Eclipse and ADT, but you probably don't want to do that.
2. Use Annotation Style AspectJ and let Android Studio treat the aspect code as Java code.  You won't get any cross-references, navigation, or content assist, but the IDE will not complain of compile errors.

---

**EDIT:** There is an [IntelliJ plugin for AspectJ](http://intellij.expertsystems.se/aspectj.html).

Comment: Slight correction: IntelliJ IDEA does have AspectJ native syntax support, just not as sophisticated and complete as Eclipse.

Comment: I was rather talking about [built-in AspectJ support](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/aspectj.html) than the external plug-in for post-compile time weaving.

Comment: Still not correct. [IntelliJ Ultimate](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) has ["native" support for AspectJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/aspectj.html) via bundled Jetbrains plugin.

The [AspectJ weaver plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1127?pr=idea) - which I am the author of - was created before Jetbrains added AspectJ support. It is no longer maintained, but may still work for non-Ultimate editions of IntelliJ based products, such as IntelliJ Community and Android Studio.